# How to access a SQL database from a Windows service?

Tags: c#, sql-server, windows-services, windows-10

I am trying to develop an windows service for Windows 10 (64bit), which intends to insert record in local MS SQL Server (v.11) periodically.

It installed and ran successfully, but no record is inserted. I tried both  `System.Timers.Timer` and `System.Threading.Timer`.

I also tried to insert on service start event. But that also didn't work.

Here is my code:

```
public partial class Service1 : ServiceBase
{
    // System.Timers.Timer timer;
    System.Threading.Timer threadTimer;
   
    public Service1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }


    //UPDATE: I checked the following method code in a console application. It works fine.
    private void InsertRecord()
    {
        try
        {
            using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("Server=.;Database=TestDb; Trusted_Connection=True;"))
            {
                using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand())
                {
                    command.Connection = connection;
                    command.CommandText = "Insert into .....')";
                    connection.Open();
                    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    connection.Close();
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }
    }

    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        InsertRecord(); //This line not executed also.

        TimeSpan tsInterval = new TimeSpan(0, 2, 0); //2 minute interval.
        threadTimer = new Timer(new TimerCallback(threadTimer_Elapsed)
            , null, tsInterval, tsInterval);


        //timer = new System.Timers.Timer();
        //timer.Interval = 10000;
        //timer.Elapsed += Timer_Elapsed;
        //timer.Enabled = true;
        //timer.Start();
    }

    private void threadTimer_Elapsed(object state)
    {
         InsertRecord();
    }

    //private void Timer_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
    //{
    //      InsertRecord()
    //}

    protected override void OnStop()
    {
        threadTimer.Change(Timeout.Infinite, Timeout.Infinite);
        threadTimer.Dispose();
        threadTimer = null;

        //timer.Stop();
    }
}
```

What did I miss here?

Comment: Make sure your insert code works and check if your service is running from windows services.

Comment: An empty catch block is a good way to stay in the dark...

Comment: You are using `Trusted Connection=true`. Does the user that your Windows Service run under have permissions to access the database and run the query?

Comment: If it is not reaching `OnStart` then you have a service startup failure.  Look at the Windows Event Log

Comment: Also, it would help considerably if you add some sort of logging so you can see what errors are happening when running the service.

Comment: Also you can attach your service process to your project and debug yourself, to see what is the problem.

Comment: @ SeM - ՍեՄ - Insert code block works fine.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In your SQL Server, allow NT AUTHORITY/SYSTEM to server Role as sysadmin.

### Follow the screenshots-

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Change the Run As setting on the service to run as your own personal account. This will provide the same security environment as your console test. This will allow the service permission to log into SQL Server.

Then change the service to "Local System" or similar and it will fail - you need to then grant "Local System" rights to access the database.

Also - an empty Catch block is the reason you are posting to SO - if you coded the simplest of error handler and loggers you would get your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You did not provide a lot of information about your connection string, but as @NightOwl888 pointed out, the problem may have to do with your use of *Trusted_Connection=True*.

If you are using Sql Authentication (as opposed to Windows Authentication) to connect to the Sql server, I believe you need to set *Trusted_Connection=False*.

This should allow your connection string credentials to be used (rather than the machine name/Windows service account/etc.).